# Page transition with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i have followed the samples and currently using  event aggregator  router  for my application in backbone.

so basically i might not use anchor element at all instead i have any element on click  event triggering router event.

I still feel that i might be missing something what is the downside of this way of navigating versus directly putting  in link via template compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple benefits of using a normal anchor tag with a hash route over having a click event trigger a routing change:

- It will make your site easier for search engines to index, thus improving SEO.
- It will allow users the ability to easily right or cmd click and open your page in a new tab/window.